# For loop is adding a tab itself

Tags: html, c, for-loop, io, cgi

I am writing a program to write my .html files rapidly. These .html files mainly contain the questions and answers. Options are MCQ(multiple choice question) form. First question goes well with this program but when I enter the 2nd question this shifts to right by one tab and also the options. I don't get it why. Code is here:

```
int main(){    
    int track=0;
    int thread=0;
    int question_no;
    char options[4][50];
    FILE *fp = fopen ("test.html", "w");
    printf("\n\aHow many questions?");
    scanf("%d",&question_no);
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) ;
    char question[question_no][100];

    for(track=1;track<=question_no;track++)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"\n<div class=\"question\"> ");
        printf("\n\aQuestion number %d.",track);
        fgets(question[track-1],sizeof(question[track-1]),stdin);
        fprintf(fp,"\nQ%d. %s </div>",track,question[track-1]);
        fprintf(fp,"\n<div class=\"options\">");
        fprintf(fp,"\n<form>");
        for(thread=1;thread<=4;thread++)
        {
            fprintf(fp,"<label><input type=\"radio\"id=\"q%dop%d\" name=\"q%d\" value=\"q%do%d\">",track,thread,track,track,thread);
            printf("\n\aOption. %d:",thread);
            fgets(options[thread-1],sizeof(options),stdin);
            fprintf(fp,"\n%d. %s",thread,options[thread-1]);
            fprintf(fp,"</label><br/>");
        }
        fprintf(fp,"\n</form>");
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shifts to right by one tab"? Can you please show expected output, as well as actual output?

Comment: Outputs for both questions is same in .html source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing `</div>`.

```
for(track=1;track<=question_no;track++)
{
    fprintf(fp,"\n<div class=\"question\"> ");
    printf("\n\aQuestion number %d.",track);
    fgets(question[track-1],sizeof(question[track-1]),stdin);
    fprintf(fp,"\nQ%d. %s </div>",track,question[track-1]);
    fprintf(fp,"\n<div class=\"options\">");    // This div is never closed!
    fprintf(fp,"\n<form>");
        for(thread=1;thread<=4;thread++)
            {
                fprintf(fp,"<label><input type=\"radio\"id=\"q%dop%d\" name=\"q%d\" value=\"q%do%d\">",track,thread,track,track,thread);
                printf("\n\aOption. %d:",thread);
                fgets(options[thread-1],sizeof(options),stdin);
                fprintf(fp,"\n%d. %s",thread,options[thread-1]);
                fprintf(fp,"</label><br/>");
            }
    fprintf(fp,"\n</form>");
    fprintf(fp,"\n</div>");    // Add this row to close the div
}
}
```

Comment: No it's not helping too.
I think the next question becomes nested to previous question.
So you're right that I am missing a </div> but .... :-|

Comment: In that case you probably have other HTML problems as well. You should check the resulting HTML with a validator. For example http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: hmmmm. . . You are right. But mozilla firefox is doing that part for me.

Comment: hey you were right! Actually I placed </div> outside the for loop. :P